# param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Rails. Getting the error below. I understand what the issue is, but not sure how to fix it?

Error - param is missing or the value is empty: customer

```
  def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(
        :first_name, 
        :last_name, 
        :email, 
        :password, 
        :password_confirmation)
    end
   end
```

DetailsController.rb

```
 class My::Account::DetailsController < MyController

 def show
   @customer = current_user
 end

 def update
   @customer = current_user
   @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
   if @customer.errors.any?
     render :action => :show
   else
     redirect_to my_account_details_path, :notice => 'Account details updated'
   end
    end

   private

   def customer_params
      params.require(:customer).permit(
        :first_name, 
        :last_name, 
        :email, 
        :password, 
        :password_confirmation)
    end
   end
```

View

```
 .account.container
.row
    = render :partial => '/my/account/sidebar'
    .section
        %h2 Your account details

        = simple_form_for @customer, :url => my_account_details_path, :method => :put, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |form|
            .field
                = form.input :first_name

            .field
                = form.input :last_name

            .field
                = form.input :email, :as => :email

            %hr
            %h4 Leave password fields blank to keep the existing password
            %hr

            .field
                = form.input :password, :input_html => { :value => '' }
            .field
                = form.input :password_confirmation, :input_html => { :value => '' }

            .field-actions
                %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "submit"} Save
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `url` points to the UPDATE path of the record? i.e. `:url => update_my_account_details_path`? Also, you should not have to set manually all these options for `simple_form_for`, the following should work `= simple_form_for @customer, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}`

Comment: What's the value of the `params` hash (maybe update this with the full error message/backtrace?)

Comment: how does your model look like?

Comment: @DylanMarkow Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"6XrIxzMDyBpI4mcHqvGV9gvxDMa7pyY5c7lDrUYjnpA=",
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"",
 "last_name"=>"",
 "email"=>"xxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because it is coming through as `user` and not `customer`. Which I believe is because you are using `current_user` which is a `User` and not a `Customer` (guessing from the code). Change it to be `params.require(:user).permit(blah)`