# param is missing or the value is empty: usuario

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, parameters

I am learning Rails and how it works on certain aspects of web programming. I know this question has been asked many times, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681280/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty), but when I'm trying to replicate that answer I keep getting the same error. Can you please help me?

usuarios_controller.rb: (create)

```
def create
  @usuario = Usuario.new(user_params)

  if @usuario.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "The person has been created!" and return
  end
  render 'new'
end
```

user_params:

```
private
  def user_params
   params.require(:usuario).permit(:user, :pass)
  end
```

HTML code which I am using create:

```
<h1>New Person</h1>

<body>
    <%= form_tag "/usuarios/create", :method => "post" do %>
    <p>
    <%= label_tag :user, "Usuario: " %> <br>
    <%= text_field_tag :user %> 
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= label_tag :pass, "Password: " %> <br>
    <%= password_field_tag :pass %> 
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>

  <% if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development" %>
    <%= debug(params) %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the request look like in the server log (the output you get after running `rails server`)? You should see something like `Started POST "/usuarios...`.

Comment: Started POST "/usuarios/create" for ::1 at 2016-06-02 10:23:13 -0700
Processing by UsuariosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kBMgnKUkwHhW/YJ2lnPZ33ZQMRRl8wBYqjkjpF/svdFIl2BxlkwKyL5aG4kA1Z7JdeAraOQ3rII4gU5f9/tFxA==", "user"=>"abc", "pass"=>"123", "commit"=>"Search"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: usuario):
  app/controllers/usuarios_controller.rb:57:in `usuario_params'
  app/controllers/usuarios_controller.rb:11:in `create'

Answer (score 1):

Please update your form on view new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Person</h1>

<body>
    <%= form_for @usuario do |f|%>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :user, "Usuario: " %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :user %> 
    </p>
    <p>
    <%= f.label :pass, "Password: " %> <br>
    <%= f.password_field :pass %> 
    </p>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>

  <% if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development" %>
    <%= debug(params) %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

and please add in your controller

```
def new
  @usuario = Usuario.new()
end
```

Comment: I got that to work, apparently it was username and password and not user and pass.

Answer (score 1):

That form is generating parameters in the form of `{"user"=>"abc", "pass"=>"123"}`, while your `user_params` method is expecting `{"usuario"=> {"user"=>"abc", "pass"=>"123"}}`. You can either change the form or change the `user_params` method.

Comment: I've changed the form and now it works. Now the problem comes with signing in with that username and password